# Add field information to file before upload to sharepoint via microsoft-graph

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the c# client library.

When I upload a file, I want to be able to set one of the Fields (SharePoint column) for that file.
I've tried to update the `FieldValueSet` from the `DriveItem.ListItem` that is returned after a call to `PutAsync<DriveItem>(filestream)` Like this

```
var newfile = await gClient
    .Sites[mySIteId]
    .Drives[myDriveId]
    .Items[mySubFolderId]
    .ItemWithPath("newFile.txt")
    .Content
    .Request()
    .PutAsync<DriveItem>(fs);

var li = await gClient
    .Sites[mySIteId]
    .Drives[myDriveId]
    .Items[newifle.Id]
    .ListItem
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();

li.Fields.AdditionalData.Add("Title", "My New File Title");

await gClient
    .Sites[mySIteId]
    .Drives[myDriveId]
    .Items[newifle.Id]
    .ListItem
    .Request()
    .UpdateAsync(li);
```

But I get this exception:

> ServiceException Field 'id' is not recognised

The above requires 3 calls to the API, but I cant see a way to add the Field when the file is uploaded in one call either.

**Updated information as requested -**

If I try to set only 1 field then the 'id' still appears in the JSON. Here is the actual code and the 'cleaned' JSON

```
    var fs = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\TestImage.jpg", FileMode.Open);
    var newfile = await gClient.Sites[SPSiteId]
      .Drives[LibraryId]
      .Root
      .ItemWithPath("TestImage.jpg")
      .Content
      .Request()
      .PutAsync<DriveItem>(fs);
    var li = await gClient.Sites[SPSiteId]
      .Drives[LibraryId]
      .Items[newifle.Id]
      .ListItem
      .Request()
      .GetAsync();
   var d = new Dictionary<string, object>();
   d.Add("Title", "This should be the title");
   li.Fields.AdditionalData = d;

    await gClient.Sites[SPSiteId]
      .Drives[LibraryId]
      .Items[newifle.Id]
      .ListItem.Request()
      .UpdateAsync(li);
```

First Call:

`PUT /v1.0/sites/xxxxxx.sharepoint.com,af844170-6c96-448b-bb75-b1144fa09f3c,d3904f65-6367-4071-9201-e96ea7c3c5d7/drives/b!cEGEr5Zsi0S7dbEUT6CfPGVPkNNnY3FAkgHpbqfDxdeiLjGMWnChSroudPhjGXRg/root:/TestImage.jpg:/content HTTP/1.1`

[image]

Second Call:

`GET /v1.0/sites/xxxxxx.sharepoint.com,af844170-6c96-448b-bb75-b1144fa09f3c,d3904f65-6367-4071-9201-e96ea7c3c5d7/drives/b!cEGEr5Zsi0S7dbEUT6CfPGVPkNNnY3FAkgHpbqfDxdeiLjGMWnChSroudPhjGXRg/items/01QX3GBJL3RSNVFPDYGBG2FKKARXI7TSBV/listItem HTTP/1.1`

[image]

Third Call (Response is `HTTP 400 Bad Request`):

`PATCH /v1.0/sites/xxxxx.sharepoint.com,af844170-6c96-448b-bb75-b1144fa09f3c,d3904f65-6367-4071-9201-e96ea7c3c5d7/drives/b!cEGEr5Zsi0S7dbEUT6CfPGVPkNNnY3FAkgHpbqfDxdeiLjGMWnChSroudPhjGXRg/items/01QX3GBJL3RSNVFPDYGBG2FKKARXI7TSBV/listItem HTTP/1.1`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you're updating a record, you don't pass in the entire object. Instead, pass in only the fields you want to change:

```cs
var li = new ListItem();
li.Fields.AdditionalData.Add("Title", "My New File Title");
await gClient
    .Sites[mySIteId]
    .Drives[myDriveId]
    .Items[newifle.Id]
    .ListItem
    .Request()
    .UpdateAsync(li);
```

When you pass in the full object, you're passing in several read-only properties. Microsoft Graph will assume any values you specify should be applied and fail if any of those values target a read-only property.

Comment: Tried that. Created a new dictionary and then added my single field. Then set the dictionary to the `ListItem.Fields.AdditionalData`, but it fails with the same error and if I inspect it with Fiddler there is an 'id' field added in the JSON.

Comment: Can you add the request and response captured using Fiddler? Include the client library calls that generated that request.